# xdebug in phpinfo() is not showing

Tags: php, xdebug

I have literally spent an entire day on solving the issue for xdebug not showing on `phpinfo()`. I've checked the file path is correct.

Comment: you need to give more informations ... follow the install informations http://xdebug.org/docs/install and check where is the problem

Comment: What operating system are you on? What is the full file path of the `php.ini` file you edited? What did you change? Did you amend your console or web server ini file? Are you running `phpinfo()` in the console or the web server?

Comment: Windows 7 Home Premium

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 Home Premium, 
the contents of the php.ini file regarding xdebug are :

```
;zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
;xdebug.profiler_append = 0
;xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
;xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
;xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "C:\xampp\tmp"
;xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s"
;xdebug.remote_enable = 1
;xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
;xdebug.remote_host = "127.0.0.1"
;xdebug.remote_port = 9000
;xdebug.trace_output_dir = "C:\xampp\tmp"
```

the full path of the php.ini file is:
C:\xampp\php\php.ini

I changed the ;xdebug.remote.enable from 0 to 1 by opening the XAMPP and then config and then PHP, and then it disappeared from phpinfo.

I run phpinfo both in console and in webserver